# How to change a file to be not executable through python?

Tags: python, execution

I need to change the permissions on a file so that it cannot be executable. I still need to be able to read it through `open("filename", 'rb')`. How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Questions should show at least an attempt to tackle the problem.

Answer (score -1):

change it to a text file
a text file can't be executed but read